# Sql grouping and getting rows by a max field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
  T1 | T2 | T3
  ------------
  A  | 2  | XY
  A  | 1  | XA
  A  | 4  | XZ
  B  | 2  | XF
  C  | 3  | XA
  C  | 7  | XY
  D  | 1  | XL
  D  | 2  | XF
  E  | 3  | XA
  E  | 6  | XZ
  E  | 2  | XY
  F  | 3  | XL
  F  | 2  | XZ
```

I'm trying to GROUP BY T1 and get the MAX(T2) and T3 in the same MAX(T2) row; how can I get it without another select?

Comment: please, review your 'accept answers' policy if you want people to answer your questions

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM table outertable
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t1, MAX(t2) as `mx` FROM table GROUP BY t1
) innertable ON outertable.t1 = innertable.t1 AND outertable.t2 = innertable.mx
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't support analytic functions (a-la Oracle or MS SQL Server), so unfortunately you can't (do it without a second query).

The MySQL query would look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM YOUR_TABLE YT1
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT T1
        FROM YOUR_TABLE YT2
        WHERE YT1.T1 = YT2.T1
        GROUP BY T1
        HAVING YT1.T2 = MAX(T2)
   );
```

You can play with it in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4f75/3).

CAVEAT: MySQL is not very good at optimizing EXISTS. Convert it to JOIN in case your measurements show a performance problem..

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH A AS (
  SELECT T1, MAX(T2) AS T2 FROM MyTable GROUP BY T1
)
SELECT A.T1, A.T2, B.T3
FROM A INNER JOIN MyTable AS B
  ON  B.T1 = A.T1
  AND B.T2 = A.T2
```

Two caveats:
- Yes, it has two selects, but don't underestimate what the server can optimize
- My sample assumes T2 is unique within one group of T1

Comment: Seems MySQL doesn't support Common Table Expressions. Sebas' answer is the same as mine though minus CTE. Go w that one.